# managing static data within WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, static

I am working within a solution that has a static logging object in a library that is shared among the projects.  This is how it is structured:

```
public class AppLog
{
  private static string _logFile;
  private static string _appName;

  public static string AppName
  { 
    get { return _appName; }
    set 
    {
      _appName = value;
      InitLogFilePath(); // initializes _logFile according to _appName
    }
  }

  public static Write(string msg) 
  {
    // writes to _logFile
  }
}
```

It works fine for the various Windows apps and Windows services:  They can initialize AppLog.AppName upon startup and `AppLog.Write` can be called throughout the code.  Shared modules write to a file named according to the initialization of `AppName`.

The problem I have is using this within WCF web services.  The web services are configured for `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`.  `AppLog.AppName` is being initialized according to `ServiceHostBase.Description.Name`.  But since multiple web services run within the same AppDomain this static data is shared.  So one ws call sets `AppLog.AppName` and it is changed by the next call, which may have a different `ServiceHostBase.Description.Name`.

How can this be restructured so that `AppLog.Write` can still be used throughout the projects in my solution but handle the naming differently for each web service?

If could tell whether the code is running within a web service, and if I could retrieve the ServiceHostBase.Description of the service, then I could maintain a lookup for the appropriate file name.  But I have not yet found a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way your logging is structured there is not a good solution.

Most logging libraries are structured so that you create an instance of the logger, pass the instance any application specific data (like AppName), and then store that instance in a private static member. The static storage is in the application, not the logging library. This avoids the sharing conflict that you have and still only creates a small fixed number of logger instances.

To illustrate the point, here's a standard [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) example from [CodeProject log4net tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial). This code passes the current class name to the instance of the logger.

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
    (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

My suggestion is to look at changing to log4net or any of the other logging packages available on NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Given your situation, AppName is not where is should be. You need a per-webservice logging facade that hold the AppName and pass the core "Write" logic down to your current AppLog. Then each of the web service has its own LogFacade instance.

```
class LogFacade
{
  public string AppName {get; private set;}

  LogFacade(string appName)
  {
    AppName = appName;
  }

  public void Write(string msg) 
  {
    AppLog.Write(string.format("[{0}]{1}", AppName, msg));
  }
}
```

Or as ErnieL said, take a look at log4net.

Comment: regarding log4net: I can't introduce new libraries/dependencies right now.  Looking at the example code you gave I don't think that can work:  AppName needs an instance and Write is a static method.

Comment: @jltrem, yeah you are right. I simply copied your AppLog. Write and AppName should be consistent in terms of being instance or static.

Comment: OK, so my problem still stands:  when calling this from different assemblies how can I determine the proper instance of LogFacade?  If I can identify whether I am running in a Web Service, and if so which WS is calling it, then I can identify the logger instance.